# HTTPS Everywhere doesn't work all the time

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, security, exit-relays, https

I tried to access http://uniquemachine.org and tor-browser/HTTPSeverywhere-add-on reached it without warning me.

Would you know why ?

How to automatically warn me at every single http:// i'm trying to access ?

Is it safe to test the tor-browser fingerprint on that website given that it's http only ?

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS Everywhere does not block all non-https requests since it would block a significant fraction of the Internet for users, hurting usability. Instead, it uses a ruleset to only modify requests for specific domains. You can search the list here: https://atlas.eff.org/index.html. Note that `uniquemachine.org` is not in the list, so the HTTPS Everywhere extension does not do anything for this domain. You can ask the website owner to add themselves to the list [here](https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#contributing-rulesets).

You can enable the EASE (Encrypt All Sites Eligible) mode in HTTPS Everywhere which supposedly [blocks all unencrypted requests](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/faq#what-do-the-different-colors-of-the-https-everywhere-icon-mean). To do this you must first right-click on the toolbar in Tor Browser, select "Customize", drag the HTTPS Everywhere icon to the toolbar, open a new tab, click on the HTTPS Everywhere icon on the toolbar, and enable "Encrypt All Sites Eligible" mode. Enabling this option may make you more fingerprintable due to non-default settings.

Firefox itself also now has an option to block all non-https requests, so this feature may come to Tor Browser in the future.